# Can an Azure Function be Executed for Multiple Environments

Tags: dependency-injection, azure-functions

I've encountered a dependency injection scenario which I cannot find a way through.
We currently have an Azure function.
We are using dependency injection via the `FunctionsStartup` attribute.
That all works fine, until I get asked to make it work for multiple environments.
The tester found it too onerous to deploy to 7 different environments, so I was asked to re-jig the function so that it runs (in a loop) for those environments.
That means 7 different `IConfigurations` and somehow having 7 separate compartmentalised IOC registrations of services.

I can't think of a way of doing that, without significantly re-structuring the way abstractions are being resolved. Even if you set up registrations in a loop and inject an `IEnumerable` of a service, when it goes to resolve a child dependency, it just pulls the last one registered, rather than the one which was meant to correlate with the current item being iterated.

So, something like this (using Autofac):

###### Registration

```
foreach (var configuration in configurations)
{
    containerBuilder.Register<ICosmosDbService<AccountUsage>>(sp =>
    {
        var dBConfig = CosmosDBHelper.GetProjectDatabaseConfig(configuration.Value, Project.Jupiter);
        return CosmosClientInitializer<AccountUsage>.Initialize(dBConfig);
    }).As<ICosmosDbService<AccountUsage>>();
}
```

###### Usage

```
private readonly IEnumerable<IAccountUsageService> _accountUsageService;


public JobScheduler(IEnumerable<IAccountUsageService> accountUsageService)
{
    _accountUsageService = accountUsageService;
}
    
[FunctionName("JobScheduler")]
public async Task Run([TimerTrigger("0 */2 * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation($"Job Scheduler Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");

    try
    {
        foreach (var usageService in _accountUsageService)
        {
            var logs = await usageService.GetCurrentAccountUsage("gfkjdsasjfa");
            // ...
        }
    }
```

I realise this kind of DI usage is not ideal (and does not even work).

Is there a way to structure an Azure Function such that it can execute for different configurations in a compartmentalised manner? Or is this really just fighting against the technology?

Comment: are you using consumption plan ? have you estimated the cost ?

Comment: Yes. We are already using the function for 7 configurations. We just want to process them in one run, rather than deploy it 7 times. Incidentally, I found the WithMeta feature in Autofac and Resolved Parameters. I think I can probably achieve the desired outcome, but some significant work will be required to configure the container with this kind of configuration. The whole thing is pretty yuck, but my overlords are asking me to look into it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a couple of ways to do this - either inject the right dependencies into the function constructor, or resolve them dynamically using a service-locater type approach with a named instance.

Let's consider the second approach and what it would mean for your implementation. As you demonstrated, you'd be looping through your instances and  resolving the dependency you want to use, then invoking it

```
foreach (var usageService in _accountUsageService)
{
    var logs = await usageService.GetCurrentAccountUsage("named-instance");
    
    logs.DoSomething();
}
```

This is technically possible, but now you're doing batch processing - you're doing more than once piece of work that's been triggered by a single event (the timer object), which means you have to deal with a couple of extra problems. What should you do if there's a failure with one of the instances, and what to do if one of the instances is running slowly?

Ideally, you want functions to do the smallest bit of work they can, and complete quickly - You don't want failure or slowness with one *particular*  instance impacting the other instances. By breaking it down to the smallest piece of work (think, one event trigger does one piece of work) then you can take advantage of the functions runtime for things like retries on failures, and threading and concurrency is now being done for you by the runtime.

You could then think about a couple of ways you could do this. a) multiple function signatures and a service resolver approach, e.g.

```
public class JobScheduler
{
    public JobScheduler(IEnumerable<IAccountUsageService> accountUsageService)
    {
        _accountUsageService = accountUsageService;
    }

    [FunctionName("FirstInstance")]
    public Task FirstInstance([TimerTrigger("%MetricPoller:Schedule%")] TimerInfo myTimer)
    {
        var logs = await _accountUsageService.GetNamedInstance("instance-a");
        logs.DoSomething();
    }

    [FunctionName("SecondInstance")]
    public Task SecondInstance([TimerTrigger("%MetricPoller:Schedule%")] TimerInfo myTimer)
    {
        var logs = _accountUsageService.GetNamedInstance("instance-b");
        logs.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

or b), multiple classes with the necessary dependencies injected

```
public class JobSchedulerFirstInstance
{
    public JobSchedulerFirstInstance(ILogs logs)
    {
        _logs = logs;
    }

    [FunctionName("FirstInstance")]
    public Task FirstInstance([TimerTrigger("%MetricPoller:Schedule%")] TimerInfo myTimer)
    {
        _logs.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

I'd personally lean towards multiple classes approach, and register named instances with my container. A bit of extra wire up work needed, but you'll end up with lots of small classes that all look very similar that are basically jus t plumbing that the functions runtime executes.

Comment: Thanks. That does make sense. Separating it out like that. Configuring the container is the biggest piece of work. But if it means we don't have to change the existing structure of the existing objects graphs, that's the win. The "main" project uses IServiceCollection and I was at least able to convince the architect that it was incapable of this. We just need to teach the container (Autofac) how to resolve our object graphs in the "contextual-resolving way" and I was half-way on the way to that. Cheers.